# How to fit multiple ImageVIew in HBox, and GridPane (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, imageview, fxml, gridpane, hbox

I'm using FXML. I have a `GridPane` (6x7) and inside of that I have a `HBox` (at 2,2 grid position). In that `HBox` I have 10 `ImageView`. I want to display 10 images taking equal space, and without crossing the grid. How to do this as relative sizing?
Here are the screenshots.

**What I want**

[image: What I want]

**How it is appearing**

[image: How it is appearing]

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "I want to display 10 images taking equal space, and without crossing the grid". The images are inside the grid, how will they cross the grid? Please provide additional information, if possible with visual presentation of what you want.

Comment: @Heman Kundu you mean to fit in that specific cell like a grid or enlarge the cell to fit all images or shrink the images to fit in a row?

Comment: @Sunflame Yes, resize the image to fit in that cell only. And when I am resizing the the window, images should also be resized too. Like relative size. And note that I have HBox containing those ImageViews.

Comment: Have you tried to bind every image's width to the hBox's withdProperty divided by nr of images?

Comment: I did this.
    


    `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            ImageViewArray.get(i).setPreserveRatio(false);
            ImageViewArray.get(i).fitWidthProperty().bind(hbox.widthProperty());
            ImageViewArray.fitHeightProperty().bind(hbox.heightProperty());
        }`

But didn't work.

Comment: You should divide ImageViewArray.get(i).fitWidthProperty().bind(hbox.widthProperty()); this with the number of images like: ImageViewArray.get(i).fitWidthProperty().bind(hbox.widthProperty().divide(10));

Comment: @Sunflame No, tried this same result. Still not working. I think ImageViews are fitting properly in HBox, but what about the HBox fitting in GridPane cell?

Comment: Can you post your code? Surely what will happen is that the column containing the `HBox` will simply expand so it will be able to contain the `HBox` (with all its images). Why do you think the `HBox` is not fitting inside its grid cell?

Comment: Picture 2 is showing that the `HBox` is going out of cell 2,2. Actually I want to resize the `HBox` and as well as `ImageView`s depending on `GridPane`'s size, So that I can have more `HBox` and `VBox` in other cells and they don't overlap.(..not like this [See this ScreenShot](https://imgur.com/a/0mab7) )